# How to save a .txt file as .doc trough vba

Tags: vba, doc

First question here. What I am trying to do is to open a txt file on word and with a macro do the following:
1. Get the name of the file
2. Apply the changes I want in the document
3. Save a PDF and a DOC version.
4. Close the document.

Problem is on step one, when I am on step one Word will open the .txt file on a WordModel document so the name I get is allways "normal.dotm". And what i need is to, for example, open the file car.txt and get the name "car" so I can save the pdf and doc version with that name.

The piece of code I have used to get the name, so far, is this:

```
 Dim esse As String
 esse = ThisDocument.Name
 MsgBox (esse)
```

Any Ideas? Thks in advance.

Comment: Word changes the extension when you select .doc type in the Save As dialog. You can Record Macro to check the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more digging on the old web and I have found a solution.

```
 Dim path As String
 Dim name As String

 path = ActiveDocument.FullName
 name = Replace(Dir(path), ".txt", "")
```

Comment: Rather than using `.FullName` and then getting rid of the path info via a `Dir(path)` "fudge", just use `.Name` - so your code would become `name = Replace(ActiveDocument.Name, ".txt", "")`